# Find out if post is private on tumblr?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

If a post is private on tumblr, I want to add a 'private' image to the page. Is there any way I can find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any variables in the [theming guide](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes), so it doesn't seem to be possible to use a special `class` or `id` value.

If you might like to program, you could maybe (I don't understand much of this stuff) use [the API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) which knows "**state**":

> Indicates the current state of the post
>
> States are `published`, `queued`, `draft` and `private`

Another (rather dirty) method could be to parse the URL path with JavaScript, because private posts start with `/private/`. If present, you could add a `class` value like "private" to the `body` element with JS.